# UIPickerViewDataSource vs UIPickerViewDelegate logic

Tags: ios, uitableview, uipickerview, uipickerviewdatasource, uipickerviewdelegate

Why aren't methods like `– pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` part of `UIPickerViewDataSource` instead of `UIPickerViewDelegate` as it is currently? After all, the titles are data...

This seems very inconsistent to me. For example, `UITableViewDataSource` contains both the methods `– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` which seems logical.

Why then for `UIPickerView` are the methods giving the number of rows and the methods giving the actual rows separated between `UIPickerViewDataSource` and `UIPickerViewDelegate`? Is there some logic to this I've missed?